# Async action causing problems

Tags: reactjs, redux

Hi I am trying to fetch data from the redux store and then trying  to use it in an async action. But I am not getting a defined value in the async action:

Here is my code:

```
import axios from "axios";
import store from "../../store/store";
let token;

function getToken() {
  let newToken = store.getState()
  token=newToken.auth.authToken;
  return token;
}
store.subscribe(getToken);


export default axios.create({
  baseURL: "http://localhost:4000/api/v2/",
  // timeout: 1000,
  headers: {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`
  }
});
```

Could someone help where are we going wrong ?

Comment: We need to see your action creator

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
     import axios from "axios";
     import store from "../../store/store";

     function getToken() {
       let newToken = store.getState()
       let token=newToken.auth.authToken;
       return token;
     }

     export default axios.create({
       baseURL: "http://localhost:4000/api/v2/",
       // timeout: 1000,
       headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${getToken()}`
       }
     });
```